# MediatR Pipeline Priority

Tags: mediator, mediatr

How can I set the priority of `PipelineBehavior`s?
I have 3 pipeline. I want to execute `AuthorizationPipeline` first. If the `AuthorizationPipeline` throws any SecurityException, I am not going to execute other pipelines.

Answer (score 4):

From the github wiki of MediatR: "Just register the behaviors in the order you would like them to be called."

https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Behaviors#registering-pipeline-behaviors

Comment: In this situation, if I have multi layer and my pipelines are seperated, it is not make sense for me. For example my logging and validation pipelines are in ```Core``` layer and my transaction pipeline is ```Business``` layer. For example I want to execute transaction pipeline middle of them of all. How can I handle it when service registration extensions seperated between core and business layer?

Comment: what you want was in discussion here: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/pull/509        not sure you can control the order

Comment: You can always register all pipelines in a separate file. For example you could have all the pipelines in a project named shared and all your other layers could reference that one.

Comment: @AbdulkadirKG You could define your pipeline behavior classes in your respective projects and then register them all with the DI container in one place* in the sequence you want them to be called, keeping in mind DI container-specific ordering controls noted on the MediatR PR link previously posted by  spyros__. *The "one place" is your application composition root (https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).